# C# : Using struct , List and enum; format exception

Tags: c#, list, exception, struct, enums

I have enum called Department that has abbreviations. (e.g. CSIS, ECON etc.)

I have struct Course with fields name, number of the course(e.g. 101 Fundamentals Of Computing just the number)

I created the constructor with four parameters.

In Program cs I created the List of these courses. with the order of (name(which is string), Department(I got this through calling Department type in enum), CourseCode(enum members like CSIS)and credit hours).

I was required to print all the courses through toString().

```
    public string Name
    {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Number 
    {
         get { return number; }
         set { number = value; }     
    }

    public int CreditHours 
    {
         get { return numOfCreditHours; }
         set { numOfCreditHours = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{ -30, 0}--{4, 1}/{2}--{3:0.0#}", name,     Department, number, numOfCreditHours);
    }
```

This is where I created my List: in Program cs.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Course course = new Course(courses);

        foreach (Course crs in courses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" , ", crs));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(); 

       //Array.Sort(courses);

       Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<Course> courses = new List<Course>()
    {
         new Course("Fundamentals of Programming", Department.CSIS, 1400, 4),
         new Course("Intermediate Programming in C#", Department.CSIS,2530, 3),
         new Course("Introduction to Marketing", Department.MKTG,1010, 3),
         new Course("Algorithms and Data Structures", Department.CSIS,2420, 4),
         new Course("Object Oriented Programming", Department.CSIS, 1410, 4)
    };
```

I get format exception. I know why I get it. Because of string type. but some how I need to do it. Please help me with some explaining. and what I should do to get it right. Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with string.format

Comment: I was trying to create the tab that was required. It should look like four columns.

Comment: You're attempting to display a type (`Department`).  When you create a new `Course`, where is the department being stored?  (i.e. `Department.CSIS`)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you swapped places in string format:

```
 return String.Format("{0,-30}--{1,4}/{2}---{3:0.0#}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing indexes in the format string in `"{ -30, 0}--{4, 1}/{2}--{3:0.0#}"`.

- `"{ -30, 0}"` must be `"{0, -30}"`.
- `"{4, 1}`" must be `"{1, 4}"`.

Then, returns must be:

```
return String.Format("{0,-30}--{1,4}/{2}--{3:0.0#}", name, Department, number, numOfCreditHours);
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. my problem about getting format exception remains though. Do you have any suggestion about that?